# Does version 12.10 support AMD graphics HD 6450

Tags: unity, 12.10, graphics

Running 12.10 (64 bit) / Unity / on HP Pavillion elite , Intel core i7 (3.2ghz), 12 gb memory

Graphics is listed as unidentified, need help please

Thanks in advance
Pete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version 12.10 supports that graphics without problems.
If this command:

```
/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
```

Outputs all Yes evyrything is ok.
You can try this to fix unidentified graphics:

```
sudo apt-get -y install mesa-utils
```

And reboot.

Comment: Thank You "About This Computer" now identifies graphics!